# Application crashes on load browser

Tags: android, eclipse, browser

I'm trying to get the browser function in my Android application to work but the application crashes upon load. Here's the code when the new activity is loaded:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    WebView webview = new WebView(this);
    setContentView(webview);

    webview.loadUrl("http://erik-edgren.nu/weather");
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);

    WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
}
```

And here is the LogCat:

```
04-05 13:51:20.224: D/dalvikvm(742): GC freed 2673 objects / 169288 bytes in 107ms
04-05 13:51:20.354: D/AndroidRuntime(742): Shutting down VM
04-05 13:51:20.354: W/dalvikvm(742): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
04-05 13:51:20.364: E/AndroidRuntime(742): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
04-05 13:51:20.373: E/AndroidRuntime(742): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{weather.right.now/weather.right.Browser}: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
04-05 13:51:20.373: E/AndroidRuntime(742):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
04-05 13:51:20.373: E/AndroidRuntime(742):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
04-05 13:51:20.373: E/AndroidRuntime(742):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
04-05 13:51:20.373: E/AndroidRuntime(742):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
04-05 13:51:20.373: E/AndroidRuntime(742):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-05 13:51:20.373: E/AndroidRuntime(742):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-05 13:51:20.373: E/AndroidRuntime(742):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
04-05 13:51:20.373: E/AndroidRuntime(742):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-05 13:51:20.373: E/AndroidRuntime(742):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-05 13:51:20.373: E/AndroidRuntime(742):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
04-05 13:51:20.373: E/AndroidRuntime(742):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
04-05 13:51:20.373: E/AndroidRuntime(742):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-05 13:51:20.373: E/AndroidRuntime(742): Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
04-05 13:51:20.373: E/AndroidRuntime(742):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:172)
04-05 13:51:20.373: E/AndroidRuntime(742):  at weather.right.Browser.onCreate(Browser.java:23)
04-05 13:51:20.373: E/AndroidRuntime(742):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-05 13:51:20.373: E/AndroidRuntime(742):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
04-05 13:51:20.373: E/AndroidRuntime(742):  ... 11 more
04-05 13:51:20.404: I/dalvikvm(742): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
04-05 13:51:20.484: I/dalvikvm(742): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

How can I fix this problem?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**: The new LogCat

```
04-05 14:00:40.893: D/dalvikvm(783): GC freed 2724 objects / 171288 bytes in 136ms
04-05 14:00:41.044: D/AndroidRuntime(783): Shutting down VM
04-05 14:00:41.064: W/dalvikvm(783): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
04-05 14:00:41.064: E/AndroidRuntime(783): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
04-05 14:00:41.074: E/AndroidRuntime(783): android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {weather.right.now/weather.right.Browser} did not call through to super.onCreate()
04-05 14:00:41.074: E/AndroidRuntime(783):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2461)
04-05 14:00:41.074: E/AndroidRuntime(783):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
04-05 14:00:41.074: E/AndroidRuntime(783):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
04-05 14:00:41.074: E/AndroidRuntime(783):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
04-05 14:00:41.074: E/AndroidRuntime(783):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-05 14:00:41.074: E/AndroidRuntime(783):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-05 14:00:41.074: E/AndroidRuntime(783):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
04-05 14:00:41.074: E/AndroidRuntime(783):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-05 14:00:41.074: E/AndroidRuntime(783):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-05 14:00:41.074: E/AndroidRuntime(783):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
04-05 14:00:41.074: E/AndroidRuntime(783):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
04-05 14:00:41.074: E/AndroidRuntime(783):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-05 14:00:41.094: I/dalvikvm(783): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
04-05 14:00:41.124: I/dalvikvm(783): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
04-05 14:00:43.176: I/Process(783): Sending signal. PID: 783 SIG: 9
04-05 14:00:43.994: D/LocationManager(798): Constructor: service = android.location.ILocationManager$Stub$Proxy@44e95780
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, And let me know what happen

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
    WebView webview = new WebView(this);
    WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    setContentView(webview);

    webview.loadUrl("http://erik-edgren.nu/weather");
}
```

Comment: sorry, I forget to put super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 line starting of onCreate().

Comment: Many thanks! Your answer solved my problem :D I'll accept your answer when I can

Comment: Actually, when you request any window feature like, getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
 then its always set to first of setContentView() of activity. So android nutshell can construct that view.. Else it throw the exception you faced first.

Comment: Ah. Ok :) Thanks for the information. I'll keep that in mind next time

Comment: And also in staring of onCreate() of activity you have to called super.onCreate() which call back to main application context for override this method. So it solved your second exception.

Answer (score 1):

The error says `requestFeature() must be called before adding content`. Try this (also added calling the `super.onCreate`):

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstancsState);
    WebView webview = new WebView(this);

    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);

    WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    setContentView(webview);
    webview.loadUrl("http://erik-edgren.nu/weather");
}
```